# How to use an argument's value to build a `.collection` method for an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm not sure what the correct terminology is for my question, but is it possible to use an argument's value to "build" its appropriate `.collection` method?

For instance, a Submission has_many images, tags, and documents. And depending on what the user is interacting with, I'd like to create the appropriate association.

Initially, I had it set up for only the tags...

```
def add_to_submission(task, user, tag)
  sub = Submission.find_or_create_by(task: task, user: user)
  sub.tags << tag
end
```

But is there a way I can generalize it further so that the third argument can by more dynamic? So rather than *only* accept a tag, it could be used like

`add_to_submission(@task, @current_user, @new_image)`

Something along the lines of...

```
def add_to_submission(task, user, associated_item)
  sub = Submission.find_or_create_by(task: task, user: user)
  items = associated_item.pluralize
  sub.items << associated_item
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic calling of methods `.send` can be used.  You can pass a symbol of the method name.  You should be able to do something like this, but I would make sure to have good unit tests for your method.

```
def add_to_submission(task, user, associated_item)
  submission = Submission.find_or_create_by(task: task, user: user)
  children = associated_item.pluralize.to_sym
  submission.send(children) << associated_item
end
```

Comment: Thank you @lacostenycoder! 

Would you mind sharing why you wouldn't recommend this approach? Maybe something you'd recommend instead?

Comment: I didn't think about it too much.  I suppose so long as you have good unit tests for the method it could be ok.  If it works for you, great.  If you passed something unexpected, acception would be raised. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense @lacostenycoder, thanks again for your help!